# Difference between Stream.CopyTo and MemoryStream.WriteTo

Tags: c#, stream, httphandler, memorystream

I have a HttpHandler returning an image through `Response.OutputStream`. I have the following code:

```
_imageProvider.GetImage().CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

`GetImage()` method returns a `Stream` which is actually a `MemoryStream` instance and it is returning 0 bytes to the browser. If i change `GetImage()` method signature to return a `MemoryStream` and use the following line of code:

```
_imageProvider.GetImage().WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

It works and the browser gets an image. So what is the difference between WriteTo and CopyTo in MemoryStream class, and what is the recommended way to make this works using `Stream` class in `GetImage()` method signature.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`WriteTo()` is resetting the read position to zero before copying the data - `CopyTo()` on the other hand will copy whatever data remains after the current position in the stream. That means if you did not reset the position yourself, no data will be read at all.

Most likely you just miss the following in your first version:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: i think copyTo is keeping the source while writeto isnt.

Comment: where did you get that info ? can you please supply link ?

Answer (score 12):

According to reflector, this is the CopyTo() method definition:

```
private void InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
{
    int num;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    while ((num = this.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, num);
    }
}
```

I dont see any "remains mechanism" here... It copies everything  from `this` to destination ( in blocks of buffer size ).

Comment: Just to keep the page consistent: the _IternalCopyTo_ method described  _Reads_ from current stream into buffer - reading starts from the current position of the stream (index and offset parameters are index and offset in the buffer) - that is the "remains mechanism"