# How to close GZipStream in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I came across a an exception saying "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream." and after some googling, the solutions ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722192/how-do-i-use-gzipstream-with-system-io-memorystream)) seemed to point out that the cause was not closing the stream.

So after some digging around it seems not only the Close method does not exist in the PCL also the Flush method does nothing according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `Dispose`?

Comment: They are wrapped in a using clause so they should be disposed of I think

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?