# How to compress memory stream into memory stream using gzipstream?

Tags: c#

Hello my problem is that I need to compress MemoryStream with GZipStream into MemoryStream if possible into the same MemoryStream that method gets as parameter. If this can't be achieved how can I make it so it is the most memory efficient.

---

Here is my current method and it is giving me **System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support reading.'** for compress.CopyTo

```
public static void GZipCompress(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        compress.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most memory efficient is likely to avoid the output memory stream completely. Are you going to be streaming the compressed data somewhere else, like a file, a socket or a string? Then use that directly instead of a memory intermediate. (The same applies to the input, of course.)

Comment: I have to put MemoryStream to Stream which is writing to Ftp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use GZipStream with System.IO.MemoryStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722192/how-do-i-use-gzipstream-with-system-io-memorystream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy the stream to itself, at least not without a *lot* of work.  Just allocating a new MemoryStream for the compressed data is simple and reasonably efficient.  eg

```
public MemoryStream GZipCompress(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var newStream = new MemoryStream((int)memoryStream.Length / 2); //set to estimate of compression ratio

    using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(newStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        memoryStream.CopyTo(compress);
    }
    newStream.Position = 0;
    return newStream;
}
```

Here's an **untested** idea for how to perform in-place compression of a MemoryStream.

```
public void GZipCompress(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var buf = new byte[1024 * 64];
    int writePos = 0;

    using (GZipStream compress = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var br = compress.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (br == 0) //end of stream
            {
                break;
            }
            var readPos = memoryStream.Position;
            memoryStream.Position = writePos;
            memoryStream.Write(buf, 0, br);
            writePos += br;

            if (memoryStream.Position > readPos)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Overlapping writes corrupted the stream");
            }
            memoryStream.Position = readPos;
        }
    }
    memoryStream.SetLength(writePos);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
}
```

Comment: But then I would have 2 memory streams in memory woudln't I? What if they are very big?

Comment: Then you would have two big streams :).  If you _really want to_ you could probably reuse the main stream.  it will blow up if any block of data fails to actually compress, as mathematically some blocks must.  But see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: I tried your code not the one replacing memoryStream with zipped one but your first snippet and it still gives me error **System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support reading.'** compress.CopyTo(newStream);