# How to wait for a task to finish

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, process

I've got a Windows Form, where I've got a report being exported to PDF format.

After the report is generated, I would like to have the application terminated completely. I have added an `Application.Exit()` clause, however this sometimes closes the process while exporting is still happening.

Hence, I would like to close the application only if the exporting is complete.

I have tried the following:

```
   while(true) 
   {
    if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForInputIdle())
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
   }
```

**and also:**

```
while(true) 
{
    if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Responding)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

None have worked however - the application still sometimes closes before the export is complete.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not a `Task`, as in `Task` class, but a task, as in job.

Comment: Yes, I meant a task in the logical sense.

Comment: Don't check against the current process...  start a child process, and make the main process wait for it to finish before it exits.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question

Comment: but why not start the report generation in a different process and wait for it completion?

Comment: @GuruStron - That could be another approach, however I would like to solve it as it is for now :) If I cannot, then I shall start the export in a separate thread.

Comment: Show the code for starting the export; that might helps us tell you how to wait for it -- maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start exporting in another process and wait for it to finish (check out the related post: [Wait till a process ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends)).

If you don't want that, you can check whether the file to which the exporting is done exists and whether it is locked (check out [Wait Until File Is Completely Written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982104/wait-until-file-is-completely-written)).

Comment: This answer assumes that the application that's waited for actually quits after exporting. You didn't mention that it does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the application is designed to be responsive to user interactions, both ways will close the application even though it is still working.

Maybe you should monitor the output of the application? That is: If the PDF file is present, the process is done. Or rather: If the PDF file is present and hasn't been modified for 15 seconds or something, exit the application.

Comment: I'd like to avoid delays as much as possible however, as I need the application to be as fast as possible - thus would like to exit as soon as the exporting is complete.

Comment: Yes, but there's no way of knowing when the application is done from the "outside".

Comment: So it's not possible to simply check if the process is in an idle state, or something similar? As I imagine once the exporting is done, the process would be idle since there would be no other job to process.

Comment: "Idle" means that no window messages are pending. The application can still be busy.