# Quickest way to read contents from xml file

Tags: c#

I have a file watcher appliation that on occassion encounters a contention issue with the file that it needs to read.  I have added a some code to deal with that in the form of

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Here is the code I am using to get the information I need from the file

```
                using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(fullFilePath))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose(); 

                foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
                {
                    foreach (XElement element in el.Elements())
                    {
                        if (element.Name == "var1")
                        {
                            aVal = element.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        if (element.Name == "var2")
                        {
                            bVal= element.Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My question is this:  Is there a quicker way to read the contents of the file, there by releasing any lock my application my have on the file?

I updated the code to read from the file as follows:

```
                lock(_lock)
            {
                using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(fullFilePath))
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlTextReader);

                    foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
                    {
                        foreach (XElement element in el.Elements())
                        {
                            if (element.Name == "AccessionNumber")
                            {
                                accessionNumber = element.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (element.Name == "PatientID")
                            {
                                patientID = element.Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works great in the debugger, but does not work when used via a release built.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can copy the file and then read the copied one instead of the original

Comment: @MisterPositive, have you tried profiler to get the problem places? Also using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); isn't good practice. Instead of it use Mutex or EventWaitHandle

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan could you provide a code sample for EventWaitHandle?  This was a one off application I was asked to write -- my background is in ASP.NET / MVC

Comment: @MisterPositive, sure, but give me more details. Do you have sources to apps which creates and reads this file?

Comment: I do not sadly.  This file is created by another third party application, and when this file is created or changed, my application needs to take action at that point.

Comment: @MisterPositive, so there is the chance that while you're reading the file, another app can change it?

Comment: There is a chance, but its very slight.  ( like less than 1% )  In this case I am ok with throwing a message into the application log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124929/discussion-between-artavazd-balayan-and-misterpositive).

Comment: Why the down votes?  I showed code and asked a very specific question.  Sometimes I don't get some of the users of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue resolved by implementing retry mechanism for the file locking from this post, which was the reason I asked the original question of efficiency.

[FileStream and a FileSystemWatcher in C#, Weird Issue "process cannot access the file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739242/filestream-and-a-filesystemwatcher-in-c-weird-issue-process-cannot-access-the)

the answer for me was provided by @Dag on the post above.