# How to fix "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Folder\New Text Document.txt' because it is being used by another process"?

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when a new file is added to a folder:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Folder\New Text Document.txt' because it is being used by another process.

I am trying to find a solutions here on SO but none has worked for me.  My code at the moment now is:

```cs
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Created:  {0} File Name:  {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name)).ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
```

**EDIT**

The error gets thrown here:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(e.FullPath)) --> HERE
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            file = reader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

So every time I add a new file I get the above error?

Thanks

Comment: See this previous answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739242/filestream-and-a-filesystemwatcher-in-c-weird-issue-process-cannot-access-the]

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I just tried that it still doesn't seem to work.  I can add the first file, but when I add another one it crashes.

Comment: Hi I have updated my Question with some more code

Answer (score 0):

The file may be opened in your system. Make sure its closed/deleted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created?view=netframework-4.8