# FileSystemWatcher C# - cannot access file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher, system.io.file

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` to detect directory changes, and after that I read file content and insert it to database.

Here's my code:

```
private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

public MainWindow()
{
    try
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetFiles();

        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetFiles())
        //   .ContinueWith(task =>
        //   {
        //   }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //..
    }
}

public bool GetFiles()
{
    _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Globals.iniFilesPath, "*.ini");
    _watcher.Created += FileCreated;
    _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    return true;
}

private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
            string[] newStringArray = content.Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('=') + 1)).ToArray();

            ChargingStationFile csf = new Product
            {
                Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(newStringArray[1]),
                Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(newStringArray[2]),
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(newStringArray[3]),
                FileName = fileName
            };

            ProductController.Instance.Save(csf);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I run this code with ***CTRL+F5*** I received this message:

[image]

But If I go with ***F5*** (Debugging mode) than I receive this and not this error about cannot access process and item is sucessfully saved. This is confusing me really..

Should I dispose watcher? or something like that? Maybe I'm missing something here?
[image]

This is first time I'm using FileSystemWatcher, obliviously something is really wrong here..

P.S I've found out that this line is causing an exception:

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
```

how come?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: I think you can rewiew this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739647/2844593

Comment: @Marlonchosky I've tried earlier with that post but code below while never executes it looks like file is never ready, really strange...

Comment: I recently wrote an answer. I hope that helps!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.ReadAllLines()` cannot access the file when it is open for writing in another application but you can use a `FileStream` and `StreamReader` instead.

Replace `string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);` with the following code and you should be able to read the contents of the file regardless of whether it is open in another application:

```
List<string> content = new List<string>();
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        content.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739647/2844593) answer:

> Most likely what is happening here is that the FileCreated event is
>   being raised and tries to process the file before is has been
>   completely written to disk.

So, you need to wait until the file has finished to copy. According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982222/2844593):

> From the documentation for FileSystemWatcher:
>
> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file
>   is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated
>   event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged
>   events.

So, a workaround for your case will be to create a list of strings containing the paths of the files that could not be read in the Created method handler, and re-process those paths in the Changed event of the FileSystemWatcher (read the comments in the code) :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public MainWindow() {
        try {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetFiles();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private bool GetFiles() {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\TestFolder", "*.ini");
        _watcher.Created += FileCreated;
        _watcher.Changed += FileChanged; // add this.
        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        return true;
    }

    // this field is new, and contains the paths of the files that could not be read in the Created method handler. 
    private readonly IList<string> _waitingForClose = new List<string>();

    private void FileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        if (_waitingForClose.Contains(e.FullPath)) {
            try {
                string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
                string[] newStringArray = content.Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('=') + 1)).ToArray();

                MessageBox.Show($"On FileChanged: {string.Join(" --- ", newStringArray)}");

                // Again, process the data from the file to saving in the database.

                // removing the path, so as not to reprocess the file..
                _waitingForClose.Remove(e.FullPath);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show($"Exception on FileChanged: {ex.Message} - {e.FullPath}");
            }
        }
    }

    private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        try {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) {
                string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
                string[] newStringArray = content.Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('=') + 1)).ToArray();

                MessageBox.Show($"On FileCreated: {string.Join(" --- ", newStringArray)}");

                // process the data from the file to saving in the database.
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // if the method fails, add the path to the _waitingForClose variable
            _waitingForClose.Add(e.FullPath);
            //MessageBox.Show($"Exception on FIleCreated: {ex.Message} - {e.FullPath}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could work, but if the file is a little heavy and the copy takes more than one second? are you tried @Roxy'Pro

Comment: Yes I've tried 5MB file, anyway biggest file I received is like 100KB so this might work hmm interesting this things about files  -.-

Comment: Mmm I have my doubts, but if it works for you, great! @Roxy'Pro

Comment: I'm receving really small ini file with 3 lins only quantity, amount, price and that's it.. it shouldn't be problem, soon I will update my questin to post what I've changed and I'll try your solution too!

Comment: That's a tiny file :) for your case that will work perfectly, however consider a solution with a more general approach, for the future, in other cases of files that take longer to copy. Anyway, the way you found works, it's just adds a line of code, although it can improve @Roxy'Pro

Comment: @Roxy'Pro `Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread for one second. This is not good, especially if the current thread is the UI thread. I suggest `await Task.Delay(1000)` instead.