# FileSystemWatcher works 3-5 times before throwing exceptions - C#

Tags: c#, ioexception, filesystemwatcher, file-conversion, argumentnullexception

File comes in over EDI as .today. I need to change it to .txt and move it to another folder. Everything works just fine for about 3-5 files, then starts throwing exceptions. I tried handling those, but that doesn't solve the problem. I'm also getting sporadic (filename cannot be null) exceptions as well. I just can't seem to figure this out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace FileConverterService
{


    class ConverterService
    {



        //Configure watcher & input
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

        public bool Start()
        {
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\FTP_base\temp", "*.today");

            _watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileCreated);

            _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            return true;
        }




        //Configure output creation and append file name to include .txt extension
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        private void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
                string content = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);
                string upperContent = content.ToUpperInvariant();
                var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
                var convertedFileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath) + dateTime + ".txt";
                var convertedPath = Path.Combine(dir, convertedFileName);

                File.WriteAllText(convertedPath, upperContent);


            }
            catch (IOException f)
            {
                if (f is IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught"); //was just testing
                }
            }

            MoveConvert();
        }

        //Move converted file to EDI processing folder
        public static void MoveConvert()
        {
            try { 
            string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
            string rootFolderPath = @"C:\FTP_base\temp\";
            string moveTo = @"C:\FTP_base\INbound\inbound_" + dateTime + ".txt";
            //string moveTo = @"F:\FTP_base\Office Depot\INbound\inbound_" + dateTime + ".txt";
            string filesToMove = @"*.txt";   // Only move .txt

            string myfile2 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, filesToMove).FirstOrDefault();
            string fileToMove = myfile2;

            //moving file
            File.Move(fileToMove, moveTo);


                MoveOriginal();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (e is IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File already exists."); //was just testing
                }
            }
        }


        public static void MoveOriginal()
        {
            try { 
            string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
            string rootFolderPath2 = @"C:\FTP_base\temp\";
            string moveTo2 = @"C:\FTP_base\archive\archive_" + dateTime + ".archive";
            //string moveTo2 = @"F:\Xcelerator_EDI\OfficeDepot\DataFiles\Inbound\Archive2\archive_" + dateTime + ".archive";
            string filesToMove2 = @"*.today";   // Only move .today


            string myfile = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath2, filesToMove2).FirstOrDefault();
            //foreach (string file in fileList)

            string fileToMove2 = myfile;

            //moving file
            File.Move(fileToMove2, moveTo2);

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (e is IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("IO Exception Occurred"); //was just testing
                }
            }
        }



        //Stop Service control
        public bool Stop()
        {
            _watcher.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it only works once before throwing exceptions, sometimes does 5 or 6 in a row before throwing. Very weird.

Comment: in which line does it happen ?

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` is notoriously difficult to use because it has a lot of error states. If you're open to using Rx and don't mind code created by another fulfillment company, I have [a wrapper](https://idcomlog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IdComLog.Reactive/FileSystem.cs) (also on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdComLog.Reactive/)) I created to make it a whole lot more reliable.

Comment: Stanley, it jumps around. Sometimes I get my "Exception Caught" message, and sometimes I get the others. When those don't throw, I get the "Filename cannot be null" exception.  I'm using Topshelf btw.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the files are still in use. The FileSystemWatcher event is raised when a file is created, but the creating process can still be writing to it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982104/wait-until-file-is-completely-written) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'll keep researching