# C# Print PDF and move file fails. File is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net

I have this process to print a pdf to a printer. My intention is that after the process completes, the file should be moved to a done folder.

However, right now I am getting a file is being used by another process error.

I have tried setting a longer waitforexit timer and checking if the file is being used but it still fails.

This is the process and move function

```
public string Process(string FilePath, string PrinterName)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Verb = "printTo",
        FileName = FilePath,
        Arguments = PrinterName
    };
    p.Start();

    if (!p.WaitForExit(5000)) 
    {
        p.Close();
        p.Dispose();
        p.Kill();
    }

    return FilePath;
}
```

Print process in the main program

```
print.Process(pol[i].FilePath, pol[i].PrinterDriver);
System.IO.File.Move(pol[i].FilePath, Input + "\\Done");
```

Comment: What happens if you change `5000` to `50000`?

Comment: Changed it to 500000 and the same issue happened.

Comment: Who do you only `Dispose` of `p` if `WaitForExit` returns `false`?

Comment: Does it work if you put `Thread.Sleep(50000);` **before** `return FilePath;`?

Comment: Have you considered waiting until the file is not locked before initiating the `Move`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982104/wait-until-file-is-completely-written

Comment: I have used the code to check if the file is not locked but that also gave me the same error. I think the only way to bypass it is to sleep the thread.

Comment: Please read the link I provided (`IsFileLocked`). It shows how to catch the exception.