# C# File Watcher Event after X minutes

Tags: c#, .net, io, filesystemwatcher

I'm creating a File Watcher `BackgroundService` where once a file has been moved to my target folder, I need to give it X minutes before I then processed with my application.

I have the file watcher set up on my target folder like so:

```
public void WatchTargetFolder(string folderLocation, string fileName = "")
{
    if (fileName == "") fileName = "Test";

     _watcher.Path = folderLocation;
     _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
     _watcher.Filter = $"{fileName}.xlsx";
     _watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
     _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

What is the best way to track the time since my file was last written to (as I've got in my `NotifyFilter`)? So that once the time has passed, my file will then move.

Comment: What about using Task.Delay in your OnChanged handler - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10982104/1997232) a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is your question related to this? [FileSystemWatcher Changed event is raised twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice). If yes, I have posted there an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice/58079327#58079327) that allows to subscribe to multiple `FileSystemWatcher` events, and get delayed notification about the last one that occurred, similar in functionality to the RX [`Debounce`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator.