# End of Stream encountered before parsing is completed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binaryformatter

I was trying to save and load a game but got this error:

> SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was
> completed.
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run ()
> (at :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize
> (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler,
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser
> serParser, System.Boolean fCheck, System.Boolean isCrossAppDomain,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage
> methodCallMessage) (at :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler,
> System.Boolean fCheck, System.Boolean isCrossAppDomain,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage
> methodCallMessage) (at :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler,
> System.Boolean fCheck,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage
> methodCallMessage) (at :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler,
> System.Boolean fCheck) (at :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) (at
> :0)
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
> (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) (at
> :0) SaveManager.LoadFile () (at
> Assets/SaveGame/SaveManager.cs:42) SaveManager.Load () (at
> Assets/SaveGame/SaveManager.cs:28)
> UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at
> <7c9c9bc2498143d08e2e3c523ff86731>:0)
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at
> <7c9c9bc2498143d08e2e3c523ff86731>:0) UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press ()
> (at D:/Program
> Files/2019.4.23f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:68)
> UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at D:/Program
> Files/2019.4.23f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:110)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute
> (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler,
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at D:/Program
> Files/2019.4.23f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T]
> (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
> eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1]
> functor) (at D:/Program
> Files/2019.4.23f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at D:/Program
> Files/2019.4.23f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:377)

```
public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private string SavePath => Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "save.text");

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        var state = LoadFile();
        CaptureState(state);
        SaveFile(state);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var state = LoadFile();
        RestoreState(state);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> LoadFile()
    {
        if(!File.Exists(SavePath))
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        using(FileStream stream = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return(Dictionary<string, object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    private void SaveFile(object state)
    {
        using(var stream = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, state);
        }
    }

    private void CaptureState(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        foreach(var saveable in FindObjectsOfType<Entity>())
        {
            state[saveable.Id] = saveable.CaptureState();
        }
    }

    private void RestoreState(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        foreach(var saveable in FindObjectsOfType<Entity>())
        {
            if(state.TryGetValue(saveable.Id, out object value))
            {
                saveable.RestoreState(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question (probably duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/a/306598/1627113

Comment: In general [**Stop using `BinaryFormatter`!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Answer (score 0):

It all solved after removing saved data file from "C:\Users<Username>\AppData\LocalLow" fixed it because the problem was that I changed data models after saving the file which made the model of the existing data in file different and made it throw errors while deserializing it.